# Tiled basemap not showing at certain scale in QGIS layout

Tags: qgis, scale, basemap, layout-manager

I'm using a certain tiled base map and am encountering difficulties with scaling in the layout-manager within QGIS.

For instance the QGIS project shows the basemap at scale 1:750, but the layout manager shows only up till 1:1800, further than that it disappears in the layout (the paper size is set to A3). I've also tested it in ArcMap 10.8 and it shows perfectly scaled in.

Is there a way to zoom in or does anyone know a workaround?

[image: Information details of said WMS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the `Export Settings/Export Resolution` in your Layout properties (`300` => a lower value like 72 or 150)

If the DPI is higher than the one used for on screen rendering within QGIS, the Layout renderer will fail to find tiles with the required native resolution at the given scale.

Layer rendering at `1:1125`:
[image]

Layout fails to render `1:1125` with the default Dpi:
[image]

Change the `Export Resolution` in the layout properties:
[image]

It shows up and exports properly